# find specific file on ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: find, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to find `MEV4_LTBP2_chr14_74992800.bam` on my `ubuntu 14.04` server.  The below command returns an empty line however `ls $HOME` shows the file. Thee below should search the home directory?  Removing the `~` shouls search the entire filesystem? Thank you :).

```
sudo find ~/ -type d -name "MEV4_LTBP2_chr14_74992800.bam"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-type d` selects for directories.  The`.bam` extension indicates that, in all likelihood,`MEV4_LTBP2_chr14_74992800.bam` is a regular file.  Use instead:

```
sudo find ~/ -type f -name "MEV4_LTBP2_chr14_74992800.bam"
```

Better yet, omit `sudo`.  If the file is in your home directory, you typically don't need root permissions.  Use:

```
find ~/ -type f -name "MEV4_LTBP2_chr14_74992800.bam"
```